# Get client IP for tcp input in Logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I have configured a tcp server in Logstash so that multiple servers can push log data to Logstash. However, I would like to add the IP address of the server the message came from as a property in the message.

Is there a variable or plugin in which the client IP can be found when using the TCP server in Logstash?

Comment: What is pushing the data?

Comment: @AlainCollins, rsyslog is pushing the data.

Comment: Why dont you use syslog input? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-syslog.html

Comment: @7171u, because I do not think that would solve the problem. Does this make the IP address of the client that connected available? Also, I am not sure if this is compatible with rsyslog (rsyslog and syslog are not the same thing).

Comment: I think 'rsylog' send logs with hostname as one field. Am I right?

Comment: @7171u, yes but I am not looking for the hostname. I am looking for the IP address.

Comment: I am not sure if you can change log fomat in rsylog conf. But you can resolve hostname to IP with `ruby` filter in logstash. check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`ruby`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-ruby.html) filter to resolve the hostname to IP

```
ruby {
        code => "
                require 'resolv'
                event['ip'] = Resolv.getaddress event['SYSLOGHOST']
               "
}
```

Where `event['SYSLOGHOST']` is parsed with `grok` filter from log file. New field `ip` is with `ruby` filter.

Comment: The hostname is not a FQDN. Since the rsyslog is not on the same server as the logstash, it is therefore not possible to resolve a hostname to an IP address since the hostname is not necessarily known at the logstash server.

Comment: thanks I hadn't found that option yet. Is there any particular reason to use this ruby code instead of the DNS plugin in Logstash?